# Trying to build explore_lite in ROS melodic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build the ROS melodic branch of  [explore_lite](https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore/tree/melodic-devel).  I get this error:

```
  Errors     << multirobot_map_merge:make /home/philip/catkin_ws/logs/multirobot_map_merge/build.make.000.log
    In file included from /home/philip/catkin_ws/src/m-explore/map_merge/src/combine_grids/merging_pipeline.cpp:46:0:
    /home/philip/catkin_ws/src/m-explore/map_merge/src/combine_grids/estimation_internal.h: In function ‘cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> combine_grids::internal::chooseFeatureFinder(combine_grids::FeatureType)’:
    /home/philip/catkin_ws/src/m-explore/map_merge/src/combine_grids/estimation_internal.h:68:14: error: ‘xfeatures2d’ has not been declared
           return xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
```

What dependency am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411604/trying-to-build-explore_lite-in-ros-melodic/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2023-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seem like the problem with the OpenCV. In [this line](https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore/blob/melodic-devel/map_merge/src/combine_grids/estimation_internal.h#L68) try to change `return xfeatures2d::SURF::create();` to `return cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create();` as the code is not defining `using namespace cv;`

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2023-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2023-01-20**:
@aarsh_t I already have openCV and need it for other projecs I'm working on. I don't want to break those other projects by doing this. Is there a way to make a seperate environment to built an openCV that will only affect this one `explore_lite` package?

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2023-01-20**:
Sorry I did not read the other answer carefully. I will updated the answer in 2 mins.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2023-01-20**:
@aarsh_t Thanks it worked! I'm now trying to use the `explore.launch` file. Would you know how to connect to `move_base server`?:
`Waiting to connect to move_base server`

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2023-01-21**:
Sorry I haven't used the package so I have no idea of how to play with it. May be you can ask to the developer or create a new question.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2023-01-21**:
@aarsh thank you